# does spring support Rest and Websocket controllers/connection at the same time?

Tags: java, spring, rest, websocket

I want to do authorization of users by rest api(and some other things) and main features by websockets in my app.
I faced with a next problem. Imagine I have super simple spring app with next controller.

```
@RestController
public class FieldController
{
    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getString", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getString()
    {
        return "[{\"id\":11, \"name\":\"qwer\"}]";
    }
}
```

It works perfect i see response in browser by this URL.
But when i try to add websocket config class to app

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer
{
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry)
    {
        registry.addEndpoint("/socket").withSockJS();
    }

    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry)
    {
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app")
        .enableSimpleBroker("/chat");
    }
}
```

browser stops to see this url. in log:

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping for GET /app/getString
```

i don't know why and google doesn't know. maybe because spring considers it as websocket controller. Question is does someone ever seen such working behaviour? At least I want confirm that this shouldn't work or confirm that i did something wrong. Thank you

Comment: Yes, this is supported normally; you use different annotations to indicate a WebSocket controller. This is most likely a fairly ordinary mapping issue. I think you have this backwards, as you're telling Spring it should use `/app` *for WebSocket*, not for traditional MVC controllers. Turn up your `org.springframework.web` logging to DEBUG and you should get a comprehensive list of all the mappings on startup.

Comment: @chrylis Why different annotations? RestController is actually Controller+ResponseBody. for websockets we use Controller.

Comment: For WebSocket, you'll generally use `@MessageMapping`.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is a bit late, but see the following configuration and controller, adopted to your example above:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry stompEndpointRegistry) {
        stompEndpointRegistry.addEndpoint("/socket")
                             .withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry messageBrokerRegistry) {
        messageBrokerRegistry.enableSimpleBroker("/chat");
        messageBrokerRegistry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }
}
```

```java
@Slf4j
@RestController
public class FooBarController {

    @MessageMapping("/foobar-ws")
    @PostMapping("/foobar-rest")
    public String foobar(@RequestBody String in) {
        LOG.debug("Received {}", in);
        return "Answer to " + in;
    }
}
```

#### Testing with HTTP/REST

`POST`ing to `/foobar-rest` works as expected:

```
curl -X POST "http://localhost:8080/foobar-rest" -d "Test1"
```

Which simply logs `Received Test1` and returns `Answer to Test1` as the HTTP response.

#### Testing with WS/STOMP

Registering to `http://localhost:8080/socket` and then sending `Test2` to `/app/foobar-ws` results in the log `Received Test2`.

#### Extending the Example

First add the `@SendTo` annotation to the method:

```java
@MessageMapping("/foobar-ws")
@PostMapping("/foobar-rest")
@SendTo("/chat/loremipsum")
public String foobar(@RequestBody String in) {
    LOG.debug("Received {}", in);
    return "Answer to " + in;
}
```

Then, same as above, register to `http://localhost:8080/socket` and subscribe to `/chat/loremipsum`. When you then send `Test3` to `/app/foobar-ws`, the input gets logged (`Received Test3`) and is returned to the WebSocket client (`Answer to Test3`). The HTTP then still works as well by the way.